# Eclipse Plugin project with mockito / hamcrest

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, mockito, manifest

I have a legacy Eclipse plugin project here that seems to use mockito and a hamcrest plugin in the manifest for required plugin.
These two plugins are not found anymore.

I don't really understand why it doesn't find these plugins. It used to work a few years ago. I expected Maven automatically download them? I tried adding these plugins in the pom.xml, but that didn't solve the problem.
The project itself is running its just the test-project that has errors due to the missing mockito/hamcrest plugin.

Has anyone an idea how to fix this?

My manifest.mf looks like this:

```
Require-Bundle: org.junit,
 org.eclipselabs.recommenders.bookmark,
 com.google.guava,
  org.mockito,
  org.hamcrest
Import-Package: org.eclipse.core.resources,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs,
 org.eclipse.jdt.core,
 org.eclipse.jface.viewers,
 org.eclipse.swt,
 org.eclipse.swt.widgets
```

The mockito and hamcrest is not found.

I added them instead to the pom, hoping that would fix it, but that didn't work:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

The error in the manifest still says it can't resolve the mockito /hamcrest bundle.

Comment: Did you check http://search.maven.org/? Also post your pom.xml.

Comment: What is missing is basically there just the manifest files seems not to find it because it is not in the target platform or something.
I am not sure what the problem is and if the pom.xml is the right place to add these dependencies. It seems not to have any effect.

Comment: What kind of build environment do you have? Are you using tycho? If yes, do you have a target platform?